# iPhone iOS Amazon Scheme / URI Not Working Anymore amzn:// version 4.3.1 Deep Linking

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking

We were using scheme something like

```
amzn://content/item?id=<some valid id>
```

And was working fine, but now as of Amazon App 4.3.1, this is no longer working, the scheme is no longer provided.

So trying the scheme something like

```
com.amazon.mobile.shopping://content/item?id=<some valid id>
```

we get the message in the Amazon App

```
Amazon Mobile is currently unavailable for content.
```

Any hints on this?

Comment: Turns out that iOS Amazon Scheme Deep Linking is not supported by Amazon from an email from their support.

Comment: anyone has working link for IOS

Answer (score 5):

Try this scheme on iOS device.

com.amazon.mobile.shopping://www.amazon.com/products/B00KWFCV32/

Comment: This helped !! Very Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This url scheme opens the in-app product detail page directly
**com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web://www.amazon.com/gp/product/product-id**