# Amazon Shopping Android App deep-linking?

Tags: android, deep-linking, amazon-fire-os

It might me duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577880/how-to-deeplink-to-product-page-for-amazon-shopping-app-in-android), but I'm not able to find possible solution for same.

I need to open below url of amazon product in amazon application and/or browser(if app is not installed) of android device.

String amazonUrl = "[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00Z5QLB7K/ref=s9_nps_hd_bw_bF2jAgt_g309_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_r=15604F7YD3RS9F854RB3&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=93b22a61-e004-5f82-b78b-991ff9d83753&pf_rd_i=13782311011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00Z5QLB7K)";

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(amazonUrl));
    startActivity(i);
```

Seems this url is working with Amazon for Tablets(com.amazon.windowshop), means with above code intent fire with amazon tablet app and browsers app list. But for Amazon Shopping (com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping) app and Amazon India Shopping (in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping) app , above code is not working it pop-up only list of browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deeplink to product page for Amazon Shopping app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577880/how-to-deeplink-to-product-page-for-amazon-shopping-app-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not reliable and this link may break with future Amazon Shopping App release. ([Reference-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837550/how-to-launch-amazon-shopping-app-in-android-app?rq=1): Read comment of Kazuki, [Reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693062/iphone-ios-amazon-scheme-uri-not-working-anymore-amzn-version-4-3-1-deep-li?lq=1): Answered by Satoshi Deguchi)

```
String amazonUrl = "com.amazon.mobile.shopping://www.amazon.com/products/B00KWFCV32/";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(amazonUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Where "B00KWFCV32" is ASIN unique identifier, you should be able to find at product detail page([Reference-3](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/deeplink)).

---

If someone find reliable solution for same, request you to answer over here.

Comment: I want to add dynamic search in amazon associate please help if someone know, Dynamic search are not opening inside app redirecting to browser .The link is starting with :"-https://www.amazon.in/gp/search/"

Answer (score 0):

The issue it not really on your part. Either those other two applications do not support those URLs, or use are using the wrong URL.